# Creating a log file detect on click of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, trace

Is there any way to allow me to trace button click in which webpage.

For example 
Default1.aspx
button1 click

Then in my log file.My log file will log that button1 click in default1 page .

Is possible to do this in the beginrequest event of the global.asax file? 
Please guild me a solution .

Here is my code for global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Set logfile name and application name variables

        string l4net = Server.MapPath("~/log4Net.config");
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(l4net));


    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //What should i code here???

    }
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, surely you can do it.

You can get the current page using

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
```

and the button is present in the event target

```
var button = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
```

This gets you the ClientID of your control, but you should be able to extract the control ID from it.

Comment: Thanks ya. Btw what u means extract the control ID?

Comment: I try adi . I only able  to get the current page. I not able to get which button  has been clicked :(

Comment: `ClientID` is a field generated by asp.net for controls that are nested in containers. Often if your button is called `Btn1` say in `Panel1`, the CliendID could look like `ct100_Panel1_Btn1`

Comment: Debug and inspect the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params` collection. If you clicked a button, the `__EVENTTARGET` should be present.

Comment: The __EVENTTARGET only return me null value :(

Comment: Ok . thanks . I get the value only. The problem I cannot get the value is because I click the button which response redirect to other page. Thanks very much